# Unable to override JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component which displays a list of "autocomplete" recommendations as the user is typing into the search bar. I am trying to allow for the user to also navigate the list by using the arrow keys and enter key.

[image]

When the user presses the down key for the first time, the focus variable increases by one and the HTML focus goes to the first recommendation. If they press it again, it goes to the focus variable increases by one again, and the HTML focus moves to the second recommendation, and so on. Similarly, when the user presses the up key it decreases the focus by one and moves the HTML focus to the previous recommendation. In addition, there are measures to ensure the focus index does not go outside of the possible range as well as resetting the focus index to zero when the value of the search bar changes.

I am encountering this strange error that when overriding the focus index value, it will function properly only when using the down key, and then when I press the up key it will change to the previous value form before the override. In some case this can cause the focus index to go outside of the range and then crash, since when you type longer searches it narrows down the list of recommendations.

Here are some screen shots of the console output for the focus index when searching only one letter:

[image]
[image]

Now I'll show what happens when I narrow the search and then navigate the recommendations:

[image]
[image]

Here is a working codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-tu-7itsm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `focus` should probably really be stored in a React ref so it can persist across renders and not reset to `-1` each render. You also add a new event listener each time the effect callback is triggered, but you never remove them (*AFAIK from your snippet*). Would it be possible for you to get this code into a *running* codesandbox for us to live debug in?

Comment: @DrewReese yes I'll get it up immediately. However wouldn't I want it not to persist across renders, because for example you navigate near the bottom of the list and then decide to enter another key. Then the list becomes shorter so the focus index should be reset to the first recommendation?

Comment: If your component rerenders for *any reason* at all, the focus index will reset. You likely want it to remain unless your list size updates and that is when you should check bounds, reset, etc. I'm also curious about what sort of select input this is as most that I am aware of should already be keyboard accessible.

Comment: @DrewReese I don't believe it renders for any reason at all, since the dependencies are only autocompleteContainer, value and items. All these values can change the recommendations one way or another. There are many many more variables in the overall program but I didn't include them in this snippet

Comment: You've a `let focus = -1;` right in the function body of the component, so if anything causes the component to rerender, like a parent component rerendering, then `focus` is set back to `-1`. Perhaps nothing is *actually* triggering your component to rerender, but you shouldn't count on that.

Comment: @DrewReese embedding the codesandbox now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226551/discussion-between-json-derulo-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Ok, it is exactly as I had suspected. You've enclosed *some* `focus` value in the "keyup" event handler that is mutated independently of the `focus` being reset each render cycle in the main component body and `useEffect` hook when the dependencies update.

There is even a react lint warning in your codesandbox to this effect:

> Assignments to the 'focus' variable from inside React Hook useEffect
> will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store
> it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current'
> property.

## Solution

1. Store your "focus" value in a React ref so all callback instances and hooks can reference the ***same stable value***.
2. I suggest also using a separate `useEffect` hook to manage the "keyup" event listener and cleanup function to remove it when the component unmounts. This will also keep your effect from added a new listener *every* time the effect callback triggers (*your code added a listener each render!!*).
3. I suggest also using a React ref for referencing the `"autocomplete__container"` container as direct DOM queries and manipulation are considered anti-pattern in React.

Code:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState([]);
  const [formSubmit, setFormSubmit] = useState(false);
  const [completions] = useAutocomplete(value, autocompleteValues);

  const autocompleteContainer = useRef(); // <-- ref to get DOMNode
  const focusRef = useRef(-1); // <-- ref to store stable focus value

  ...

  // Effect hook to manage keyup event handler and cleanup
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeypress = (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 38 && focusRef.current >= 1) { // <-- focus.current
        focusRef.current -= 1;
        autocompleteContainer.current.childNodes[focusRef.current].focus(); // <-- autocompleteContainer.current
      } else if (
        event.keyCode === 40 &&
        focusRef.current < autocompleteContainer.current.childElementCount - 1
      ) {
        focusRef.current += 1;
        autocompleteContainer.current.childNodes[focusRef.current].focus();
      } else if (
        event.keyCode === 13 &&
        document.activeElement.className !== "form-control"
      ) {
        setValue(document.activeElement.innerHTML);
        setQuery(document.activeElement.innerHTML);
        document.getElementsByClassName(
          "autocomplete__container"
        )[0].style.display = "none";
        setFormSubmit(true);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeypress); // <-- add listener

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeypress); // <-- return cleanup function to remove listener
  }, []);

  // Effect hook to reset focus value when list updates
  useEffect(() => {
    focusRef.current = -1;
    console.log("focus reset", focusRef.current);
  }, [value, items]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form id="search__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group>
          <InputGroup className="mb-3">
            ...
            <div
              ref={autocompleteContainer} // <-- attach DOM ref here
              className="autocomplete__container"
            >
              {completions.map((val, index) => (
                <p
                  tabIndex={index + 10}
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => updateInput({ val })}
                >
                  {val}
                </p>
              ))}
            </div>
          </InputGroup>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
      <p>{focusRef.current}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit unable-to-override-javascript-variable]

Comment: Thanks again for the great solution. I see it works properly in the codesandbox however when I change the code on my machine I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'childElementCount' of undefined" with an indication to the first else if

Comment: @JSON_Derulo If you opted to convert `autocompleteContainer` to a React ref then it is no longer an array that was previously returned by `document.getElementsByClassName`. It should be `autocompleteContainer.current.childElementCount`,